# Arch Linux - Wifi keeps disconnecting

Tags: arch-linux, wifi, netctl

I'm running Arch Linux and I use netctl for my wifi, but for some reason it keeps dropping every 5 minutes, especially fast if I don't use the internet for 5 seconds it seems. I have a USB wifi stick (ASUS USB-N13 11n).

I run netctl restart  and it works again for a few minutes.

My netctl edit looks like this:

```
Description='Automatically generated profile by wifi-menu'
Interface=wlp0s18f2u3
Connection=wireless
Security=wpa
ESSID=<wifiname>
IP=dhcp
Key=<password>
```

Comment: Disable the other network management service you have running...

Comment: How can I find if any other management service is running? I only found this:
systemctl | grep -i wifi
netctl@wlp0s18f2u3\x2dssid.service                                                   loaded active exited    Automatically generated profile by wifi-menu

Comment: I have disabled that service, will see how it works, I still have connection to wifi after reboot.

Comment: After disabling that service my internet dropped out after not using wifi for 1 minute or so.

Comment: When it dies, read your journal and dmesg...